# Java program that outputs an XML file - multiple issues

Tags: java, sql, xml, methods, db2

I'm new to this so please forgive me if I tagged something incorrectly or left something out.

I'm writing a java program (new to java also) - the purpose of the program is to generate an XML file with information from multiple databases.

The setup - I have sql.java which is the main class and has the main method.  Sql.java calls methods located in the CCReturns.java class, GBLRets.java class, and CWSReturns.java class.  Each method returns a string of XML containing pertinent information and then the main method in sql.java puts them all together in one string and creates an xml file.

Problem: One of my methods in CWSReturns should return a resultset containing 74 rows in all but is only returning the data from one of the rows.  When I put this same code into the sql.java main method all 74 rows are returned in the console but the xml file only shows the data from one of the rows and all of the data from all of my other methods is repeated even though I only need it to output once.

What would be the best way to go about fixing this issue?  I'm stumped.

Method in CWSReturns:

```
    public static String getUnitInfo(Connection connection, Statement stmt, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
        {
            String unitinfo = null;

            //Get Connection
            connection = getCWSConnection();

            //Create the SQL Query and put it into a String Variable
            stmt = connection.createStatement();

            //Pull Policy Claim Unit Information from CLM_UNIT Table
            String query = "SELECT CLUT.UNIT_TYPE AS CLUNITTYPE, CLUT.UNIT_SUBTYPE AS CLUNITSUBTYPE, CLUT.UNIT_CATEGORY AS CLUNITCATEGORY, CLUT.UNIT_IDENTIFIER AS CLUNITIDENTIFIER, CLUT.UNIT_NUM AS CLUNITNUM, " +
                            "CLUT.YEAR AS CLUNITYEAR, CLUT.MAKE AS CLMAKE, CLUT.MODEL AS CLMODEL, CLUT.VEHICLE_ID AS CLVEHICLEID, CLUT.ITEM_DESC1 AS CLITEMDESC1, CLUT.LICENSE, " +
                            "DAM.LOCATION1, DAM.DESC1, " + 
                            "UNT.UNIT_TYPE, UNT.UNIT_SUB_TYPE, UNT.UNIT_CATEGORY, UNT.UNIT_IDENTIFIER, UNT.UNIT_NUM, UNT.YEAR, UNT.MAKE, UNT.MODEL, UNT.VEHICLE_ID, UNT.LICENSE, UNT.ITEM_DESC, " +

                            //Pull Coverage Information from POL_COVERAGE Table
                            "COV.COVERAGE_TYPE, COV.DED_TYPE_CODE1, COV.DEDUCTIBLE1, COV.DED_TYPE_CODE2, COV.DEDUCTIBLE2, COV.DED_TYPE_CODE3, COV.DEDUCTIBLE3, COV.LIMIT_TYPE1, COV.LIMIT1, " +
                            "COV.LIMIT_TYPE2, COV.LIMIT2, COV.LIMIT_TYPE3, COV.LIMIT3, COV.LIMIT_TYPE4, COV.LIMIT4 " +

                            "FROM DB2ADMIN.CLM_CLAIM CLM, DB2ADMIN.CLM_UNIT CLUT, DB2ADMIN.POL_GENERAL_REC POL, DB2ADMIN.POL_UNIT UNT, DB2ADMIN.POL_COVERAGE COV, DB2ADMIN.CLM_DAMAGE DAM " +

                            "WHERE CLM.CLAIM_ID = CLUT.CLAIM_ID AND CLM.POLICY_ID = POL.POLICY_ID AND POL.POLICY_ID = UNT.POLICY_ID AND UNT.POL_UNIT_ID = COV.POL_UNIT_ID AND CLUT.UNIT_ID = DAM.UNIT_ID " +
                            "AND CLM.CLAIM_ID = 14701";

                //Execute the query and save it as a ResultSet
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                //Pull out all of the information and save it as a string
                while(rs.next())
                {
                //Retrieve by column name

                //Claim Unit Info
                String CL_UNIT_YEAR = "<CL_UNIT_YEAR>" + rs.getString("CLUNITYEAR") + "</CL_UNIT_YEAR>\n";
                String CL_UNIT_TYPE = "<CL_UNIT_TYPE>" + rs.getString("CLUNITTYPE") + "</CL_UNIT_TYPE>\n";
                String CL_UNIT_SUB_TYPE = "<CL_UNIT_SUB_TYPE>" + rs.getString("CLUNITSUBTYPE") + "</CL_UNIT_SUB_TYPE>\n";
                String CL_UNIT_CATEGORY = "<CL_UNIT_CATEGORY>" + rs.getString("CLUNITCATEGORY") + "</CL_UNIT_CATEGORY>\n";
                String CL_UNIT_IDENTIFIER = "<CL_UNIT_IDENTIFIER>" + rs.getString("CLUNITIDENTIFIER") + "</CL_UNIT_IDENTIFIER>\n";
                String CL_UNIT_NUM = "<CL_UNIT_NUM>" + rs.getString("CLUNITNUM") + "</CL_UNIT_NUM>\n"; 
                String CL_UNIT_MAKE = "<CL_UNIT_MAKE>" + rs.getString("CLMAKE") + "</CL_UNIT_MAKE>\n";
                String CL_UNIT_MODEL = "<CL_UNIT_MODEL>" + rs.getString("CLMODEL") + "</CL_UNIT_MODEL>\n";
                String CL_UNIT_VEH_ID = "<CL_UNIT_VEH_ID>" + rs.getString("CLVEHICLEID") + "</CL_UNIT_VEH_ID>\n";
                String CL_UNIT_DESC1 = "<CL_UNIT_DESC1>" + rs.getString("CLITEMDESC1") + "</CL_UNIT_DESC1>\n";
                String TAG_NUMBER = "<TAG_NUMBER>" + rs.getString("LICENSE") + "</TAG_NUMBER>\n";

                String DAMLOC = "<DAMAGE_LOCATION>" + rs.getString("LOCATION1") + "</DAMAGE_LOCATION>\n";
                String DAMDESC = "<DAMAGE_DESCRIPTION>" + rs.getString("DESC1") + "</DAMAGE_DESCRIPTION>\n";

                String UNIT_TYPE = "<UNIT_TYPE>" + rs.getString("UNIT_TYPE") + "</UNIT_TYPE>\n";
                String UNIT_SUB_TYPE = "<UNIT_SUB_TYPE>" + rs.getString("UNIT_SUB_TYPE") + "</UNIT_SUB_TYPE>\n";
                String UNIT_CATEGORY = "<UNIT_CATEGORY>" + rs.getString("UNIT_CATEGORY") + "</UNIT_CATEGORY>\n";
                String UNIT_IDENTIFIER = "<UNIT_IDENTIFIER>" + rs.getString("UNIT_IDENTIFIER") + "</UNIT_IDENTIFIER>\n";
                String UNIT_NUMBER = "<UNIT_NUMBER>" + rs.getString("UNIT_NUM") + "</UNIT_NUMBER>\n";
                String UNIT_YEAR = "<UNIT_YEAR>" + rs.getString("YEAR") + "</UNIT_YEAR>\n";
                String UNIT_MAKE = "<UNIT_MAKE>" + rs.getString("MAKE") + "</UNIT_MAKE>\n";
                String UNIT_MODEL = "<UNIT_MODEL>" + rs.getString("MODEL") + "</UNIT_MODEL>\n";
                String VEH_ID = "<VEH_ID>" + rs.getString("VEHICLE_ID") + "</VEH_ID>\n";
                String ITEM_DESC = "<ITEM_DESC>" + rs.getString("ITEM_DESC") + "</ITEM_DESC>\n";



                //Coverage Info
                String COVERAGE_TYPE = "<COVERAGE_TYPE>" + rs.getString("COVERAGE_TYPE") + "</COVERAGE_TYPE>\n";
                String DED_TYPE_CODE1 = "<DED_TYPE_CODE1>" + rs.getString("DED_TYPE_CODE1") + "</DED_TYPE_CODE1>\n";
                String DEDUCTIBLE1 = "<DEDUCTIBLE1>" + rs.getString("DEDUCTIBLE1") + "</DEDUCTIBLE1>\n";
                String DED_TYPE_CODE2 = "<DED_TYPE_CODE2>" + rs.getString("DED_TYPE_CODE2") + "</DED_TYPE_CODE2>\n";
                String DEDUCTIBLE2 = "<DEDUCTIBLE2>" + rs.getString("DEDUCTIBLE2") + "</DEDUCTIBLE2>\n";
                String DED_TYPE_CODE3 = "<DED_TYPE_CODE3>" + rs.getString("DED_TYPE_CODE3") + "</DED_TYPE_CODE3>\n";
                String DEDUCTIBLE3 = "<DEDUCTIBLE3>" + rs.getString("DEDUCTIBLE3") + "</DEDUCTIBLE3>\n";
                String LIMIT_TYPE1 = "<LIMIT_TYPE1>" + rs.getString("LIMIT_TYPE1") + "</LIMIT_TYPE1>\n";
                String LIMIT1 = "<LIMIT1>" + rs.getString("LIMIT1") + "</LIMIT1>\n";
                String LIMIT_TYPE2 = "<LIMIT_TYPE2>" + rs.getString("LIMIT_TYPE2") + "</LIMIT_TYPE2>\n";
                String LIMIT2 = "<LIMIT2>" + rs.getString("LIMIT2") + "</LIMIT2>\n";
                String LIMIT_TYPE3 = "<LIMIT_TYPE3>" + rs.getString("LIMIT_TYPE3") + "</LIMIT_TYPE3>\n";
                String LIMIT3 = "<LIMIT3>" + rs.getString("LIMIT3") + "</LIMIT3>\n";
                String LIMIT_TYPE4 = "<LIMIT_TYPE4>" + rs.getString("LIMIT_TYPE4") + "</LIMIT_TYPE4>\n";
                String LIMIT4 = "<LIMIT4>" + rs.getString("LIMIT4") + "</LIMIT4>\n";




                    //Create one large string that incorporates all of the above nodes
                    String unitinfo1 =     CL_UNIT_YEAR + CL_UNIT_TYPE + CL_UNIT_SUB_TYPE + CL_UNIT_CATEGORY + CL_UNIT_IDENTIFIER +
                                           CL_UNIT_NUM + CL_UNIT_MAKE + CL_UNIT_MODEL + CL_UNIT_VEH_ID + CL_UNIT_DESC1 + TAG_NUMBER + DAMLOC + DAMDESC +
                                           UNIT_TYPE + UNIT_SUB_TYPE + UNIT_CATEGORY + UNIT_IDENTIFIER + UNIT_NUMBER + UNIT_YEAR + UNIT_MAKE +
                                           UNIT_MODEL + VEH_ID + ITEM_DESC + COVERAGE_TYPE + DED_TYPE_CODE1 + DEDUCTIBLE1 + DED_TYPE_CODE2 +
                                           DEDUCTIBLE2 + DED_TYPE_CODE3 + DEDUCTIBLE3 + LIMIT_TYPE1 + LIMIT1 + LIMIT_TYPE2 + LIMIT2 +
                                           LIMIT_TYPE3 + LIMIT3 + LIMIT_TYPE4 + LIMIT4;

                    return unitinfo1;
                }
                stmt.close();
                rs.close();
                connection.close();
                return unitinfo;

        }
```

sql.java - main method snippet:

```
    //Get unit info
    String unitinfo = CWSReturns.getUnitInfo(connection, stmt, rs);  

    String xmlStr = (Root+mainclaimnode+mainclaiminfo+lossState+clientname+clientaddress+communicationinfo+agentname+adjustername+secondaryclientname+policyinfo+cancelpendinginfo+endmainclaimnode+claimunitnode+unitinfo+OIPName+OIPAddress+rollinjuryinfo+unitaddress+endclaimunitnode+EndRoot);

    Document doc = convertStringToDocument(xmlStr);

    String str = convertDocumentToString(doc);

    System.out.println(str);

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Temp\\TestXML.xml");
    writer.println(str);
    writer.close();
```

Output when running method from CWSReturns (only one resultset returned...)

```
<CWS_XML>
<MAIN_CLAIM_INFO>
<CLAIM_ID>14701</CLAIM_ID>    
<DATE_LOSS>2013-09-01 04:00:00.0</DATE_LOSS>
<CLAIM_MADE_DATE>null</CLAIM_MADE_DATE>
<CALLER_NAME>asdf  asdf</CALLER_NAME>
<ACTUAL_NOT_DATE>2014-02-25 10:25:00.0</ACTUAL_NOT_DATE>
<METHOD_REPORT>PHONE</METHOD_REPORT>
<NAME_TYPE_FLAG>I</NAME_TYPE_FLAG>
<NAME_TYPE>null</NAME_TYPE>
<NAME_PREFIX>null</NAME_PREFIX>
<LAST_NAME>Luke</LAST_NAME>
<NAME_SUFFIX>null</NAME_SUFFIX>    
</MAIN_CLAIM_INFO>
**<CLAIM_UNIT_INFO>
<CL_UNIT_YEAR>2014</CL_UNIT_YEAR>
<CL_UNIT_TYPE>DRIVE_OTHR</CL_UNIT_TYPE>
<CL_UNIT_SUB_TYPE>COMBO</CL_UNIT_SUB_TYPE>
<CL_UNIT_CATEGORY>DRIVE_OTHR</CL_UNIT_CATEGORY>
<CL_UNIT_IDENTIFIER>2014 Cadillac</CL_UNIT_IDENTIFIER>
<CL_UNIT_NUM/>
<CL_UNIT_MAKE>Cadillac </CL_UNIT_MAKE>
<CL_UNIT_MODEL/>
<CL_UNIT_VEH_ID/>
<CL_UNIT_DESC1>null</CL_UNIT_DESC1>
<TAG_NUMBER/>
<DAMAGE_LOCATION>Unknown</DAMAGE_LOCATION>
<DAMAGE_DESCRIPTION>Unknown</DAMAGE_DESCRIPTION>
<UNIT_TYPE>NON_OWNED</UNIT_TYPE>
<UNIT_SUB_TYPE>COMBO</UNIT_SUB_TYPE>
<UNIT_CATEGORY>NON_OWNED</UNIT_CATEGORY>
<UNIT_IDENTIFIER>NON OWNED</UNIT_IDENTIFIER>
<UNIT_NUMBER>null</UNIT_NUMBER>
<UNIT_YEAR>null</UNIT_YEAR>
<UNIT_MAKE>null</UNIT_MAKE>
<UNIT_MODEL>null</UNIT_MODEL>
<VEH_ID>null</VEH_ID>
<ITEM_DESC>null</ITEM_DESC>
<COVERAGE_TYPE>ADB</COVERAGE_TYPE>
<DED_TYPE_CODE1>null</DED_TYPE_CODE1>
<DEDUCTIBLE1>null</DEDUCTIBLE1>
<DED_TYPE_CODE2>null</DED_TYPE_CODE2>
<DEDUCTIBLE2>null</DEDUCTIBLE2>
<DED_TYPE_CODE3>null</DED_TYPE_CODE3>
<DEDUCTIBLE3>null</DEDUCTIBLE3>
<LIMIT_TYPE1>LIM</LIMIT_TYPE1>
<LIMIT1>15000.000</LIMIT1>
<LIMIT_TYPE2>null</LIMIT_TYPE2>
<LIMIT2>null</LIMIT2>
<LIMIT_TYPE3>null</LIMIT_TYPE3>
<LIMIT3>null</LIMIT3>
<LIMIT_TYPE4>null</LIMIT_TYPE4>
<LIMIT4>null</LIMIT4>
<OIP_NAME>Null</OIP_NAME>
<OIP_ADDR>Null</OIP_ADDR>
<ROLE_TYPE>DRIVER</ROLE_TYPE>
<INJURY_TEXT>head</INJURY_TEXT>
<CL_UNIT_ID>Null</CL_UNIT_ID>
<CL_UNIT_HOUSE>Null</CL_UNIT_HOUSE>
<CL_UNIT_ADDR1>Null</CL_UNIT_ADDR1>
<CL_UNIT_ADDR2>Null</CL_UNIT_ADDR2>
<CL_UNIT_CITY>Null</CL_UNIT_CITY>
<CL_UNIT_STATE>Null</CL_UNIT_STATE>
<CL_UNIT_ZIP>Null</CL_UNIT_ZIP>
</CLAIM_UNIT_INFO>**
</CWS_XML>
```

The elements in the "CLAIM_UNIT_INFO" node should repeat upwards of 74 times...

Comment: Inside the while loop you are returning. So it iterates only one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the while loop you are returning. So it iterates only one time.

Make `unitinfo` in `getUnitInfo()` method as a `StringBuilder` and inside the `while(rs.next)` instead or returning append the `unitinfo1` to `unitinfo`

```
public static String getUnitInfo(Connection connection, Statement stmt, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    StringBuilder unitinfo = new StringBuilder();

    ...

    while(rs.next()) {

        ...

        unitinfo.append("<CLAIM_UNIT_INFO>");

        //Create one large string that incorporates all of the above nodes
        String unitinfo1 =  CL_UNIT_YEAR + CL_UNIT_TYPE + CL_UNIT_SUB_TYPE + CL_UNIT_CATEGORY + CL_UNIT_IDENTIFIER +
                            CL_UNIT_NUM + CL_UNIT_MAKE + CL_UNIT_MODEL + CL_UNIT_VEH_ID + CL_UNIT_DESC1 + TAG_NUMBER + DAMLOC + DAMDESC +
                            UNIT_TYPE + UNIT_SUB_TYPE + UNIT_CATEGORY + UNIT_IDENTIFIER + UNIT_NUMBER + UNIT_YEAR + UNIT_MAKE +
                            UNIT_MODEL + VEH_ID + ITEM_DESC + COVERAGE_TYPE + DED_TYPE_CODE1 + DEDUCTIBLE1 + DED_TYPE_CODE2 +
                            DEDUCTIBLE2 + DED_TYPE_CODE3 + DEDUCTIBLE3 + LIMIT_TYPE1 + LIMIT1 + LIMIT_TYPE2 + LIMIT2 +
                            LIMIT_TYPE3 + LIMIT3 + LIMIT_TYPE4 + LIMIT4;

        unitinfo.append(unitinfo1);
        unitinfo.append("</CLAIM_UNIT_INFO>");
    }

    ...

    return unitinfo.toString();

}
```

Comment: Something so simple was causing me such a fuss!  This worked!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As @SyamS mentioned you are returning inside of your loop.

If you don't want to combine all of the rows into one `String`: One way to fix this would be to store the `String` found in the loop into an `ArrayList`, and then return the `ArrayList` of `String`.

You would have to change the return type of your method, and handle iterating through the resulting `ArrayList` when you called the method.

```
public static ArrayList<String> getUnitInfo(...){
    ArrayList<String> unitinfo = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...

    while(...){
        ...
        unitinfo.add(unitinfo1); // Instead of return
    }

    ...
    return unitinfo; // Only return at the end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because you have `return unitinfo1` inside your while loop. So it is just returning after the first row has been populated.

You need to declare `String unitinfo1` outside of the while loop, and append each line to the string during each iteration of the loop.

```
String unitinfo1;

while(condition)
{
    unitinfo1.append(nextLine);
}

return unitinfo1;
```